# Is there a way to use case_when to create a new variable but only alter the conditional value by a fixed multiple?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable `X` that returns a certain value (e.g., -4) based on the value of `name`. For each multiple of `9` starting from `1`, I would like `X` to be `4`, etc. This is the original data:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ID     name
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 B         5
3 C        10
4 D        19
5 E        25
```

And this is the expected output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  ID     name     X
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1    -4
2 B         5    NA
3 C        10    -4
4 D        19    -4
5 E        25    NA
```

While the following works, I was wondering if there is a more efficient piece of code I could use, since I have to do this up to values of 81.

```
df%>%
  mutate(X = case_when(
    name == 1 | name == 10 | name == 19 ~ -4
  ))
```

dput code

```
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
name = c(1, 5, 10, 19, 25)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with R's modulo operator `%%`. This allows you to calculate the remainder after division. So "each multiple of 9 starting from 1" is equivalent to "zero remainder when a number *minus* 1 is divided by 9."

We can test this with numbers 1 to 27:

```
((1:27)-1) %% 9 
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

To add this to a `dplyr` pipeline, we can write:

```
df %>%
  mutate(X = case_when((name - 1) %% 9 == 0 ~ -4))
```

Or alternatively:

```
df %>%
  mutate(X = ifelse((name - 1) %% 9 == 0, -4, NA))
```

I prefer the second `ifelse` makes it more obvious to readers of the code that there are only two possible outcomes.

Comment: Thank you so much. First I've heard of the modulo operator `%%` and I anticipate this to be rather handy in the future. Thanks again!